# Kotlin smartcast check is failing despite type information being available at runtime

Tags: kotlin, generics, casting, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

Essentially what I'm trying to do is smartcast an object at runtime if the variable has been set to an object of the specified type.  However, the object itself is a generic type.  The `is` type check is returning false at runtime, yet the type information is available at runtime, as evidenced by printing the class name.

So my code looks something like this:

```
val desiredObject = genericTypeWrapper.genericType

println("desiredObject is of type: {}", desiredObject::class.simpleName)

if (desiredObject is MyType) {
    println("desiredObject is MyType")
    // Do something with desiredObject
}
```

It'll compile, and the first print statement above would show: `desiredObject is of type: MyType`, but the if condition returns false every time.

---

Since `desiredObject` is a generics type, I tried an inline function with reified type, something like this:

```
inline fun <reified T> getMyType(genericTypeWrapper: GenericTypeWrapper): T? {
    val desiredObject = genericTypeWrapper.genericType

    println("desiredObject is of type: {}", desiredObject::class.simpleName)

    if (desiredObject is T) {
        return desiredObject
    }
    
    return null
}
```

I then call it like so:

```
desiredObject = getMyType<MyType>(genericTypeWrapper)
```

Assuming correct input to `desiredObject` (verified manually), the if condition should return true and execute code inside the block.  However, this also fails like the previous example, where the print statement would read `desiredObject is of type: MyType`, but the `is` check is returning false.

---

Similar code works in Java, using `instanceOf`.  I suspect that the issue comes down to type erasure, hence the above attempt.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and/or any suggestions to get around this?  I'd like to avoid an explicit `as?` cast, because the object itself is rather large, and is causing significant performance issues.

Comment: What do you mean by "desiredObject is a generics type"? Can you show us the `GenericTypeWrapper` class? By the way, an `x as? Foo` cast is no worse performing than `if (x is Foo) x as Foo else null` Size of the object should be irrelevant to checking the type.

Comment: Is MyType a class/interface, or is it an actual generic type of a class that doesn't follow generic type naming convention (one or two capital letters)? Is `getericTypeWrapper.genericType` a KType? If it isn't an actual instance of the MyType class, then it makes sense that `is MyType` would be false.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @Tenfour04: I may have misspoke.  I mean that `desiredObject` can be set to a generic type, where `GenericTypeWrapper.genericType` can be lets say `MyType` or `NotMyType`.


I was hoping to avoid an `as` cast altogether, where I could just do `if (x is Foo) { x.something }`

`MyType` is a subclass of an abstract class, the `GenericTypeWrapper` is a generic type that can be set with `MyType` or `NotMyType`

I'm not sure if it's a KType, but it should be an actual instance, I'm able to print the data in MyType (outside of the if statement of course)

Comment: You can't call a function of MyType without casting it to MyType. Maybe you don't realize, smartcasting is still doing a cast at runtime--you just don't have to explicitly type it out in your code. Your problem doesn't have to do with type erasure, or you would have a compile-time error. We need to see more context of this code to really understand it.